# overriding password_digest validation in rails 3.1 has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

So I wish to allow empty password_digest in has_secure_password, but looking at ActiveModel::SecurePassword seems like it is hardcoded:

```
validates_presence_of     :password_digest
```

Is the only way to override this is by using monkey patching?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think has_secure_password will do what you want, as you discovered.

So instead of using has_secure_password, you could write your own, basically copy the source and 'fork' it to do what you want -- only generate and validate a password if #user is not nil, is what it sounds like you want.

Or, as jtomasri suggests, you could make an Employee model and a User model -- you can use the ActiveRecord 'single table inheritance' feature to have them still both be in the same table, and have a common super-class you can still fetch upon (say, Account.find to return both Employees and Users matching your criteria).  In some ways this is the 'cleaner' solution, although it's increasing the complexity of the behind the scenes ActiveRecord stuff -- in the past single table inheritance was a bit buggy, I *think* they are behaving well these days. (Haven't used it myself in a while).

Answer (score 0):

I just had an related issue and used the :if operator for the validation.

```
validates :password ,..., :if => :employee_needs_password?
validates :password_confirmation , ... , :if => :employee_needs_password?

def employee_needs_password?
   # check whatever your condition is and return true/false 
end
```

Answer (score -1):

why would you include has_secure_password if you want an empty password or why would you implement password's if you accept empty ones. Anyways you can always implement your own digest method without using has_secure_password using BCrypt, there's a Railscast #250 Authentication from scratch where you can see this in action

Comment: yes, this is using exactly that, which is why I was asking the question above... In my system there are employees that require username (thus the password field) and employees that don't.

Comment: Then making an user model without authentication and an account model for employees that requie authenticarion